# Does anybody know if any daemons or services started by default when TBB is installed in Debian?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, debian

Does anybody know if any daemons or services are started by default the moment you install TBB ? I ask as when I shutdown my system I see some entry about Tor even though I might not have used TBB in the session.

There seem to be three packages which are installed alongwith torbrowser-launcher.

```
$ aptitude why tor
i torbrowser-launcher Depends tor

$ aptitude why tor-geoipdb 
i torbrowser-launcher Depends tor 
i A tor Recommends tor-geoipdb
```

At least here, in Debian it doesn't seem that that tbb is a standalone package.

Answer (score 1):

Tor browser bundle is a standalone package, with everything it needs running as 'standalone' from the folder you unpacked it to.

Maybe you have the separate standalone Tor package installed as well?
If so - then that one can have a daemon.

Comment: I have edited the question, perhaps you are coming from MS-Windows where this might be the case, in Debian as stated above it does not seem to be the case.